# What is the difference between WD Green and WD Caviar Green when replacing a drive?

Tags: hard-drive, compatibility

I need to replace a disk in a MyBook World Edition and it says to only use Caviar Green yet when 
I search for Caviar Green NewEgg comes back with just Green with Caviar in the description. I already have a Green drive with faster read/write. The Caviar Green drive that I found has a cache though and mine has double the cache.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning: the MyBook World Edition runs a custom version of Linux on the drive, so replacing a disk is not as simple as just taking it apart and putting a new drive in.** The MyBook Wiki has some tutorials (like http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/ultra-fast-install-for-my-book-world-edition-i-and-ii-white.) As far as your hardware question goes, I'm pretty sure WD just changed their branding to remove the caviar name on newer drives. In addition, it shouldn't matter what type/brand of hard drive you use anyway (nothing special about "caviar green"), so the point is rather moot.

Answer (score 0):

The WD products which specify the "green" drives generally do not have internal fans for cooling and depend on natural convection instead.  So one cannot willy-nilly use higher power consumption drives.  I don't know what sort of internal checking of drive versions is used by these enclosures, but I've seen occasional reports that some drives will not work at all in the enclosures.  Sorry, I didn't write down the specific details, a google search might find them :-(

Answer (score -1):

Don't touch green, they're a low performance power saver and take forever to initialize during boot. Get blue or black, blue being standard, black being high(er) performance. There's no reason why you can't use another brand or model as long as it doesn't sap more power than the power supply can provide.

If you really need to stick to green, check this spec sheet which will explain why some are slower than others http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-701229.pdf

The lower capacities are slower than the higher capacities, but not by much. It really depends what you want from the drive.

Comment: Why would the OP need a 2.5" drive?

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. I thought a 'mybook' was a laptop. That's confusing apple naming conventions for you.

Comment: @Simkill - Except there are very good reasons in this case that a energy saving product should be used.

Comment: @Ramhound I'd still use a caviar red at least. I wouldn't use a green. I have a green, it's terrible. That's just my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, at first I was like "MacBook World Edition what?" Since this is a NAS, I don't think there's any particular reason not to use a WD green, WD blue, or any other drive since a lot of IO speed will be limited by internet

Comment: I just love how you getting wrong the names, and thus the whole question, is somehow Apple's fault.

Answer (score -1):

Called support and It was still under warranty since the drive had failed and wasn't reading anyway sending it back for replacement and keeping the other drives for something else